# Recipe and ingredient questions

Tags: meta

What is the prevaling opinion on questions for recipes or favorite ingredients?  I think they are a little too broad for this forum. BrewAdvice is for focused questions. However this site is about community parcipitation so I want to get a consensus before down-voting questions.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think that questions asking for recipes are appropriate for BrewAdvice. It's just too broad. "What's a good stout recipe?" is just too subjective. It's better for a forum, like home brew talk.

A question like "I'm making a stout, and the LHBS is out of roasted chocolate malt, what's a good substitute?" works. Or "Here's my stout recipe, what yeast would you suggest?" also works.

However, as of right now, we don't have a recipe sharing tool on this site, so just asking "What's a good recipe for [style]?" isn't appropriate.

Comment: Are there plans for a recipe sharing tool? I was shocked to find here: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/366/what-are-some-good-online-sources-for-recipes that there are no social homebrew sites where you can rate recipes a-la epicurious. Seems like this community could be great for it with the right tools...

Answer (score 4):

I think that asking for critique of a specific recipe posted is fine.  However, asking for recipes is probably a needless distraction.  Most of the "do you have a recipe for" questions we have gotten so far haven't even specified all-grain or extract, making them doubly useless.

I say recipe critique yes, random "do you have a recipe for x" no.

Comment: I completely agree.

Answer (score 1):

For the recipe questions I think it's fine if it is related to advice or feedback on an existing recipe you use. Overall it is interesting to see what people will post when you ask for a recipe, but I can see how this might not be the best place for it.