# Are "Looking for clone of" questions encouraged/discouraged?

Tags: discussion, meta, recipe, policy

Title pretty much says it all...

Answer (score 7):

"Looking for clone of..." is a veiled recipe request, which is considered off topic ([Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc/1696#1696), [link](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/recipe-and-ingredient-questions), [meta](https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117/recipe-and-ingredient-questions)).

I would suggest following the guidelines established on the Cooking Stack Exchange for [dealing with recipe-related questions](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/restaurant-mimicry-questions-allowed/70#70).

Outright recipe requests should be **off topic**:

- *"How do I make [X]?"* - off topic
- *"What's the best recipe for [Y]?"* - off topic

Questions *discussing* recipes or *refining* recipes should be **allowed**:

- *"I made [X] beer. How do I get more of that that fruity piquant of brand [Y]?"* - on topic.

Answer (score 1):

According to the site proposal, those questions are discouraged.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1619/homebrewing-beer-wine-etc/1715#1715